# Xamarin.Forms change Default FontFamily in all App

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, font-family

I added custom font:

```
[assembly: ExportFont("Roboto-Regular.ttf", Alias ="Roboto")]
```

Also in `App.xaml` :

```
        <Style TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Roboto"/>
        </Style>
```

And also can add for Entry and etc...
But it is possible with one line of code change the Default Font Family which is initialized when u create the project? If is possible how?

Answer (score 2):

You would need to create your controls for label,entry,picker,etc. with the default font family. I've created labelcontrol one for you

```
public class MyFontLabel : Label
{
    public MyFontLabel()
    {
       Style = Application.Current.Resources["FontLabelStyle"] as Style;
    }
}
```

style in app.xaml

```
<Style x:Key="FontLabelStyle" TargetType="Label">
  <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Roboto"/>
</Style>
```

Use it throughout

```
<local:MyFontLabel Text="My Text"/>
```